# Handle dot (.) character in parameter name in post request

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest

I'm building a restful server to handle post requests. However, there is a dot (.) in one of the parameter names which I don't know how to handle since C# does not allow dot (.) in their variable names. The parameter name is "data.json" without the quotation.

I read some posts about C# converting dots (.) into underscores (_), so I tried to name the variable "data_json", which doesn't work, the string is empty.

Object Class:

```
public class Lead {
    public string data_json { get; set; }
    public string page_id { get; set; }
    public string page_url { get; set; }
}
```

Post Handler:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(Lead value) {
    try {
        Log.CreatePostLog(page_id + value.data_json);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, e.Message);
    }
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Done!");
}
```

Post Request Body (Cannot be changed):

```
page_url=http://ramdomurl/
&page_id=123456
&data.json={"time_submitted":["04:34 PM UTC"],"full_name":["John Doe"]}
```

When the request is made, the log shows page_id but nothing after.
It should show page_id and the Json string after it.

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET Core or the classic ASP.NET?

Comment: I'm using classic ASP.NET 4.7.2

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution is to [create a custom model binder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api#model-binders), which handles fields whose names contain the "." character, and apply this binder to the model class.

The code of the binder:

```cs
// this binder assigns form fields with dots to properties with underscores:
// e.g. data.json -> data_json
public class Dot2UnderscoreModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    // for regular fields, we will use the default binder 
    private readonly DefaultModelBinder _default = new DefaultModelBinder();

    public object BindModel(
        ControllerContext controllerContext, 
        ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        // handle the regular fields
        var model = _default.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);

        // handle the special fields
        if (model != null)
        {
            var modelType = model.GetType();
            var form = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form;

            foreach (var key in form.AllKeys)
            {
                if (key.Contains(".")) // special field
                {
                    // model property must be named by the convention "." -> "_" 
                    var propertyName = key.Replace(".", "_");
                    var propertyInfo = modelType.GetProperty(propertyName);

                    propertyInfo?.SetValue(model, form[key]);
                }
            }
        }

        return model;
    }
}
```

Note that this is a simplistic implementation, it only supports `string` properties, and its performance is not optimal. But it is a working starting point.

Now you need to apply the above binder to the model class:

```cs
[ModelBinder(typeof(Dot2UnderscoreModelBinder))]
public class Lead 
{
    //... properties
}
```

It worth noting that the controller must derive from [`Controller`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controller?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) in `System.Web.Mvc` namespace, and not `ApiController` in `System.Web.Http`, because that latter doesn't trigger model binders:

```cs
using System.Web.Mvc;

....

public class MyController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Post(Lead value)
    {
        //... do some stuff
        return base.Content("Done!");
    }

}
```

#### ASP.NET Core

Just as a side note, in ASP.NET Core the same can be achieved in a very simple way, by applying [`FromForm`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.fromformattribute?view=aspnetcore-2.2) attribute:

```cs
public class Lead 
{
    [FromForm(Name = "data.json")] // apply this attribute
    public string data_json { get; set; }

    //... other properties
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. I did exactly what you said for the model. In the controller I removed System.Web.Http and added System.Web.Mvc. I also added [HttpPost] and [HttpGet], but now when I do a simple Get it says "No HTTP resource was found..." Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

Use NewtonsoftJson PropertyName attribute:

```
public class Lead 
{
     [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "data.json")]
     public string data_json { get; set; }
     public string page_id { get; set; }
     public string page_url { get; set; }
}
```

Add nuget package:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/

Comment: It's still not working. I even tried deserializing the string but got thrown an error saying the property is null

Comment: @achaves OP shows that the request is made with "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" content type (the "classic HTML form"), and not "application/json", so Newtonsoft.Json is not relevant

Comment: @german1311 No, that didn't work. I understand what's it trying to do, but the request body isn't json to start with